# Miniature preview, loading url into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jQuery's .load(url, ...) to load a url into a div. The problem is: The result needs to be scaled down to properly fit into the layout. How can I do that?

Philip

Comment: you could maybe try to play around with the CSS zoom property, just a flippant idea though, may not work

Comment: @Danjah Thanks for the suggestion! Though it's css3 it would be ok because it's just an internal page. Well I try it..

Comment: sweet, lemme know if it works, i was thinking of trying something similar in a day or two

Comment: Is the result of the load is pure HTML? Could you give an example

Comment: No, the problem is it also contains some heavy weight javascript component. Well I solved the problem by changing the layout, so no need for rescaling. I appreciate your help and I am still interested in miniature previews in general as I kind think of a lot of ways to use them.

Comment: @Danjah Yes it works! At least if you don't have javascript widgets.

Comment: Doh, true, lots of JS correction and overriding going on no doubt :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick your favourite: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-free-website-thumbnail-generation-services/

Comment: Buf if you load the websites with jQuery you need online access, too, right? Then why not use one of those services and also write a caching mechanism on top of that, so that it doesn't query them if thumbnails have already been generated?

Comment: Those services would be over-kill. And it would be a problem because the stuff on the miniature previews is paid content. Anyways I "solved" it by changing a layout for that internal page a bit..

Answer (score 0):

set up a CSS sheet to scale down the inserted html